# Cannot call QuickBooks "query" endpoint

Tags: php, api, laravel, oauth, quickbooks

I've got OAuth working for creating a customer then loading that customer via their customer ID

However when I try to use the "query" endpoint to find a customer by name, it fails me.

I'm using Laravel and the PHPoAuthLib library. My code looks like so:

```
$oauth = OAuth::consumer('QuickBooks');
$oauth_token = unserialize(file_get_contents(storage_path("tokens/saved_data.txt")));

$storage = $oauth->getStorage();
$storage->storeAccessToken('QuickBooks', $oauth_token['access_token']);

// Check for Quickbooks donor
$result = $oauth->request("/v3/company/" . $oauth_token['company_id'] . "/query?query=SELECT * FROM Customer MAXRESULTS 1", "GET");

return $result;
```

This is returning a 400 error with the message "Unknown Version"

Trying to google this error suggests it might be an issue in signature generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured out the issue with this about two weeks ago -- updating with the answer I found:

The query needs to be URL encoded. I changed it to the following:

```
$result = $oauth->request("/v3/company/" . $oauth_token['company_id'] . "/query?query=" . urlencode("SELECT * FROM Customer MAXRESULTS 1"), "GET");
```

Everything worked perfectly